# Guzzle 3.x How to set Content-Type :application/json?

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm using old php version, so I cannot update guzzle on current server.

Is there a way to `set Content-Type :application/json`?

The code I use on my local machine (I've tried different ways to set Content-Type - it's commented-out):

```
    $client = new \Guzzle\Http\Client();
    $request = $client->post($cms_admin_api_url,
        ['headers' => [
            'user-agent' => $admin_token,
            //'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            //'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ],
        //'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        ],
        ['json'        => [
            'name' => $key,
            'image' => base64_encode($body),
            'env' => $cake_emv
        ]
        ]);
        $response = $request->send();
```

I'm getting this response:

```
POST /api/image/xxx HTTP/1.1
Content-Length:    88
Content-Type:      application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Headers:           A7t1xXXXXXXXr23vt8jL999
Host:              my_api.url.com
User-Agent:        Guzzle/3.9.3 curl/7.19.7 PHP/5.6.30
X-Amzn-Trace-Id:   Root=1-5ec66539-XXXXXXXXX9c3c667a3a
X-Forwarded-For:   118.XXXX.242
X-Forwarded-Port:  443
X-Forwarded-Proto: https

json%5Bname%5D=article%2Fartem%2Ftest77.jpg&json%5Bimage%5D=eHh4&json%5Benv%5D=localhost
```

I want to get this response:

```
POST /api/image/xxx HTTP/1.1
Content-Length:    70
Content-Type:      application/json
Host:              my_api.url.com
User-Agent:        A7t1xXXXXXXXr23vt8jL999
X-Amzn-Trace-Id:   Root=1-5ec66539-XXXXXXXXX9c3c667a3a
X-Forwarded-For:   118.XXXX.242
X-Forwarded-Port:  443
X-Forwarded-Proto: https

{"name":"article\/artem\/test77.jpg","image":"eHh4","env":"localhost"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setBody()` did the trick:

```
$client = new \Guzzle\Http\Client();

$client->setUserAgent($admin_token);

$request = $client->post($cms_admin_api_url);

$request->setBody(json_encode([
    'name'  => $key,
    'image' => base64_encode($data)
]), 'application/json');

$response = $request->send();
```